# TFS 2013 restrict tag from list?

Tags: tfs

When user adds tag, is there a way to force him to select one of "proposed list" ? I would something just like this site has, must select tag but only from the list it proposes you. 
In case not, is there a way to add a control which will disable him from the saving the WIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have TFS 2013.3 you can restrict permission to create tags. That should give you the feature that you want. If you go, in web access, to Settings | Permissions | Create Tag Definition.

[image: Settings|Permission|Create Tag Definition]

Comment: I really don't understand the question then. How can you have the ability to 'add tags' and also 'only select from the suggested values'. Those two statements are mutually exclusive.